# Let $N \lhd G $ with index $n$, such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then the relation $x^m=1$ implies that $x \in N$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $N \lhd G $ ($N$ normal in $G$)  with index $n$. I want to show that if $m$ and $n$ are such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then the relation $x^m=1$ implies that $x \in N$

I think I may be starting in a bad way considering the index of $N$ as solely the factor of Lagrange's theorem (and not as the number of cosets), for I'm not going anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: I've forgotten - does index N=n imply that for any x $\in$ N, index(x)=n (i.e. the index of the cyclic group generated by x?)

Comment: In that case I want to say that this might be relevant, but I haven't done much with algebra in over a year https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem

Comment: @WilliamKrinsman Index in that sense https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup

Comment: also why would this be true? for example if there were two normal subgroups of index n, then would x be in both of them, and one would contain the other? is there a property of n that makes this true, or is n completely arbitrary?

Comment: maybe the fact that N is a normal subgroup implies that there can only be one normal subgroup of a given index? I apologize, I should know this

Comment: If $x^m$=1, then x must have a number of cosets coprime to m? Or otherwise $x^m$ would be in another coset of x? And thus if the number of its cosets is coprime to m, then it must be in a subgroup with index coprime to n? EDIT: nevermind, Ahmed's answer is much more correct and better overall

Answer (score 2):

$x^m = 1 \implies x^m \in N \implies x^m + N = N \implies |x + N| \mid m$. But, $|x+N| \mid |G/N| = n$. Therefore $|x + N| = 1$, so $x+N = N$ and $x \in N$.

Where $|(\cdot)|$ denotes the order of $(\cdot)$.

Comment: very nice - explains the answer clearly and simply

Comment: @AhmedHussein I didn't understand why $x^m \in N$. Could you explain please?

Comment: @allanaraujo because $x^m = 1$, and $1 \in N$ ($N$ is a subgroup after all).

Answer (score 0):

Since $n$ is the order of the group $G/N$,if $x\notin N$ then $o(xN)|n$. Let $k=o(xN)$ and $x^k\in N$. Hence $k|o(x)$.